# Problema para remover elemento adicionado com jQuery

Tags: jquery

Tenho em uma página um `input`, um botão para adicionar mais `inputs` e cada um tem um botão correspondente para removê-lo.

O problema é que não consigo remover os `inputs` adicionados através do botão. Apenas o original é removido. Segue o código aqui e funcionando no [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/amandex/20u42xp1/jsFiddle)

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
<button class="add">Adicionar outro campo</button>
<br><br>
<span>
    <input type="text" name="nome" value="Original"> 
    <button class="apagar">Apagar </button>
    <br>
</span>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.add').click(function(){
        $('#content').append('<span> <input type="text" name="nome" value="Cópia"> <button class="apagar">Apagar </button></span> <br> ');
    });

    $('.apagar').click(function(){
        $(this).parents('span').remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: O problema é o escopo, coloque o apagar dentro do click do add que irá funcionar.

Comment: obrigada, ajudou mto

Answer (score 6, accepted):

você está adicionando o evento `click` a `input.apagar` antes de criar a mesma.

então coloque o `evento` a todos os `input.apagar` pertecentes a `#content` usando o método `$.on`.

Outro detalhe, o `$.parents` vai buscar todos os parentes, então se na sua arvore HTML tiver mais de um span acima do `input.apagar` ele tambem será excluido, então use o método `$.parent`, afinal você quer apenas o primeiro `span`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var add = $('.add');
    var content= $('#content');
  
    add.click(function(){
        content.append('<div><span> <input type="text" name="nome" value="Cópia" /> <button class="apagar">Apagar </button></span></div>');
    });

    content.on("click", "button.apagar", function(event){
        $(event.target).parent().parent().remove();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  <div>
    <button class="add">Adicionar outro campo</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>
      <input type="text" name="nome" value="Original" /> 
      <button class="apagar">Apagar </button>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

aqui segue uma adaptação da solução do @GabrielRodrigues

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var add = $(".add");
  var content = $('#content');

  var onApagarClick = function() {
    $(this).parents('span').remove();
  };

  add.click(function() {
    var novaLinha = $('<span> <input type="text" name="nome" value="Cópia"> <button class="apagar">Apagar </button></span> <br>');    
    $('.apagar', novaLinha).click(onApagarClick);
    $('#content').append(novaLinha);        
  });

  $('.apagar').click(onApagarClick);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  <div>
    <button class="add">Adicionar outro campo</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>
      <input type="text" name="nome" value="Original" /> 
      <button class="apagar">Apagar </button>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

O problema é o escopo, o  click do apagar só esta fazendo efeito fora do click de add, e é no add que é inserido um novo campo.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.add').click(function() {
    $('#content').append('<span> <input type="text" name="nome" value="Cópia"> <button class="apagar">Apagar </button></span> <br> ');
  });
  
  $("#content").on('click', '.apagar', function(e) {
    $(this).parents('span').remove();
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  <button class="add">Adicionar outro campo</button>
  <br>
  <br>
  <span>
 <input type="text" name="nome" value="Original"> 
 <button class="apagar">Apagar </button>
 <br>
</span>
</div>
```

Comment: seguindo a sua recomendação, sempre que ele adicionar um `input.apagar` ele vai fazer um novo attach de um evento `click` a todos os `input.apagar`, então se ele adicionar 4 `input.apagar` e clicar no primeiro que ele adicionou o método será executado 4 vezes.

Comment: @TobyMosque editado.

Comment: atualizei a minha resposta com uma adaptação da sua resposta.

Answer (score 3):

Passar o evento directamente:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').on('click', '.add', function() {
    $('#content').append('<span> <input type="text" name="nome" value="Cópia"> <button class="apagar">Apagar </button></span><br>  ');
  });

  $('body').on('click', '.apagar', function() {
    $(this).parents('span').remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
<button class="add">Adicionar outro campo</button>
<br><br>
<span>
 <input type="text" name="nome" value="Original"> 
 <button class="apagar">Apagar </button>
 <br>
</span>
</div>
```

Comment: usar o `.on` diretamente sobre elementos como `$(document)`, `$('body')` raramente é uma boa ideia... tente sempre definir um escopo menor, para resolver o problema do `AP` o escopo ideal seria o `$('#content')`